# Voltage regulator output ripple

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm designing a power supply using a 7805 regulator and I need a very low output noise voltage at 1 Hz, hopefully around 1 mVpp. Will increasing the size of the output capacitor help me do this, or should I be adding additional circuitry?

Comment: It highly depends also on the input ripple of the 7805. Why do you need a low noise voltage?

Comment: The photonics device that the PS is powering is very sensitive. They had been using a bench supply but there was too much noise coming off of it, so I threw together a makeshift battery pack with 3 1.5V batteries in series, and it almost completely got rid of the noise. It's not sustainable because the batteries drain too fast, I just wanted to see if it helped with the noise issue. Anyways, for the 1 mV ripple, anything higher than 5 mV will interfere with the photonics system in place (I don't have much physics so I can't explain the photonics system).

Comment: There are 1000's of linear voltage regulators out there. The chief advantage of the 7805 is that is cheap and multi-sourced. If low output ripple is important to you, it would be better to find a regulator that is optimized for that spec rather than for cost than to try to fix up a 7805.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The impedance of a capacitor is \$ 1/(2 \pi f C)\$ so a 1000µF cap will have 160 ohms impedance at 1Hz.

Your regulator has an output impedance too. This is due to the internal feedback loop which adjusts the output transistor drive to respond to changing load currents. This loop is not infinitely fast, and it does not have infinite gain, so it will not hold the output voltage perfectly at the set point, but at low frequencies output impedance is pretty low. Say, 0.01 ohms.

Thus, considering the two impedances in parallel, the regulator will control the output completely at 1Hz. The cap only comes into play at much higher frequencies.

The low-frequency output ripple will depend entirely on regulator noise, and the input ripple divided by regulator ripple rejection.

Why do you need 1mV ripple on 5V?

Comment: The photonics device that the PS is powering is very sensitive. They had been using a bench supply but there was too much noise coming off of it, so I threw together a makeshift battery pack with 3 1.5V batteries in series, and it almost completely got rid of the noise. It's not sustainable because the batteries drain too fast, I just wanted to see if it helped with the noise issue. Anyways, for the 1 mV ripple, anything higher than 5 mV will interfere with the photonics system in place (I don't have much physics so I can't explain the photonics system).

Comment: How much current does the thing use?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I know it's low current. Is the exact number important for this?

Comment: Exact number is not important but 50mA versus 500mA is ;) Like, less than 100mA?

Comment: I believe it uses around 150-200 mA.

Comment: OK, there are a number of very low-noise regulators, ADM7151 LT3045 LT3042 for example will give you a few µV noise. Or LT1965 if you don't like SMD. Tons of options, you can also make your own for ultimate performance, thats probably unnecessary though...

Answer (score 3):

Considering the bench supply is noisy, it's better to build a linear regulator with the AC supply from another transformer, and the LM317.

For LM317, you can add an C<sub>adj</sub> of 10uF at the Adj pin to further reduce ripple at the output. Whereas 7805 can't be done. 317 is better in terms of lower noise, better line rejection and lower output impedance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLiaKI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you explain why an LM317 is better than an LM7805? I was under the impression that the LM78xx are more or less an LM317 with values fixed internally (presumably with resistors built into the die?).

Comment: @sillyfly. For LM317, you can add an Cadj of 10uF at the Adj pin to further reduce ripple at the output. Whereas 7805 can't be done. 317 is better in terms of lower noise, better line rejection and lower output impedance.

Answer (score 2):

[Zetex Application Note 51](https://www.diodes.com/assets/App-Note-Files/zetex/an51.pdf) from 2007 describes a "Precision voltage regulation for ultra-low noise applications":

> A simple discrete regulator circuit using Zetex voltage references and transistors can realise performance
>   levels that are beyond IC regulators, whilst being of reasonable cost and with very little board space
>   overhead.
>
> [image: Zetex AN51 Precision voltage regulation for ultra-low noise applications]

It is not actually necessary to use Zetex devices; the low noise is primarily a result of all the decoupling capacitors:

> Working backwards through the circuit, the output voltage is divided by resistors R1 and R2 to match the
>   output voltage of the voltage reference U1. In the circuit with values as shown in figure 1, the reference
>   voltage (across U1) is 1.22V, and the output voltage of 3.3V is scaled easily with standard value resistors.
>   The capacitors C1 and C2 provide a path for the output noise to the error amplifier. The voltage reference
>   U1 is strongly decoupled by C3 and C4, reducing reference (and thus output) noise. Dual Diode D1 acts
>   simply to limit the size of the maximum differential input signal that may be seen by the error amplifier
>   limits. The reference signal is again decoupled at the amplifier input in order to reduce noise yet further.
>   U3 drives Q3 (with D2 for biasing), which then moderates the base current into Q1.
>
> Of note in the design of the circuit is the use of the regulator circuit's output to power the error amplifier.
>   Of course, this could give startup problems, but these are solved by the bootstrap circuit on the front end;
>   when power is first applied, the voltage reference U2 generates a base-emitter voltage on transistor Q2,
>   switching it on. This in turn generates a base-emitter voltage on Q1, the pass transistor, allowing the
>   output to rise sharply until enough voltage is available for the error amplifier to operate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: capacitive multiplier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk9xCr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would this be added to the output of the regulator or instead of the regulator?

Comment: add it to the output,